# bash - check for word in specific column, check value in other column of this line, cut and paste the line to new text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

My text files contain ~20k lines and look like this:

file_A:

> ```
> ATOM    624  SC1 SER   288      54.730  23.870  56.950  1.00  0.00
> ATOM   3199  NC3 POP   487      50.780  27.750  27.500  1.00  3.18        
> ATOM   3910  C2B POP   541      96.340  99.070  39.500  1.00  7.00         
> ATOM   4125  W    PW   559      55.550  64.300  16.880  1.00  0.00
> ```

Now I need to check for POP in column 4 (line 2 and 3) and check if the values in the last column (10) exceed a specific threshold (e.g. 5.00). These lines - in this case just line 3 - need to be removed from file_A and copied to a new file_B. Meaning:

file_A:

> ```
> ATOM    624  SC1 SER   288      54.730  23.870  56.950  1.00  0.00
> ATOM   3199  NC3 POP   487      50.780  27.750  27.500  1.00  3.18    
> ATOM   4125  W    PW   559      55.550  64.300  16.880  1.00  0.00
> ```

file_B:

> ```
> ATOM   3910  C2B POP   541      96.340  99.070  39.500  1.00  7.00
> ```

I'm not sure wether to use sed, grep or awk or anything couple them :/
So far i could just delete the lines and create a new file without these lines...

> ```
> awk '!/POP/' file_A > file_B
> ```

---

EDIT:

Does the following work for having more than one different words removed?

```
for (( i= ; i<$numberoflipids ; i++ ))
do
        awk '$4~/"${nol[$i]}"/&&$NF>"$pr"{print >"patch_rmlipids.pdb";next}{print > "tmp"}' bilayer_CG_ordered.pdb && mv tmp patch.pdb
done
```

whereas $nol is an array containing the words to be removed, $pr is the given threshold and the .pdb are the used files

Comment: @Jidder can you take a look at the edit please. that would be great :-)

Comment: Look up how to pass variables to awk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

awk

```
awk '$4~/POP/&&$NF>5{print >"fileb";next}{print > "tmp"}' filea && mv tmp filea
```

.

```
$4~/POP/&&$NF>5  -Checks if fourth field contains POP and last field is more than five

{print >"fileb";next} -If they are writes the line to fileb and 
                        skips further statements

{print > "tmp"} -Only executed if first part fails, write to tmp file 

filea && mv tmp filea -The file used, if awk command succeeds then overwrite
                        it with tmp
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth dropping in some explanation

Comment: isn't `$4~/POP/` the same as `$4=="POP"` but slower due to the test being done with a regular expression? Over 20k lines that might affects total time of execution

Comment: @Thomasleveil Its unlikely to affect performance, and no it is different. `$4=="POP"` is field 4 is equal to POP. `$4~/POP/` is field 4 contains POP. Although unlikely from OPs example, he did specify to check for POP in field 2, not if it is POP.

Comment: sorry i meant field 4!

Comment: thanks for the explanation :) does the check for the threshold work with decimals aswell? didnt get to test it so far...

Comment: ...and do i write variables in quotes?
sry for double post.

Comment: @Ueffes Yes it works for decimals and what variables ?

Comment: I editted my original question with the new code i added. I guess variables should be cleared by the edit